# Do you really get better at digesting beans?

Tags: nutrition, flatulence-gas-fart

When you eat beans you tend to have stinky flatulence because of the long carbohydrates combined with protein. But I heard that the more beans you eat, the more your digestive track will accommodate the beans, which will make digesting beans easier and thus you have less flatulence.

Is this true or just a myth?

Comment: A few years ago I went to a low fat diet and used beans as a source of protein to replace meat.  After just a couple weeks my level of flatulence went way down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The fact that the more you eat beans, the faster it digests, is not a myth.

For directions,

Try adding them into your diet in 1/4 cup increments, and increasing very slowly.

Although, there are other ways to increase the digestion rate of beans, but as for your question, it's certainly not a myth.

http://www.thefullhelping.com/10-tips-for-better-bean-digestion-a-few-announcements/

**What Makes Them So Hard to Digest?**

Besides the [phytic acid](http://www.nourishingdays.com/2010/09/what-is-phytic-acid/) contained in legumes, the harder beans such as kidney and navy beans contain oligosaccharides. **This complex sugar is impossible to digest without some help because humans do not produce the enzyme alpha-galactosidase needed to properly break it down.**

Comment: You need more than a vegan recipe site to support your claim that eating more beans decreases digestion time.

Comment: I agree. This claim should be backed with more solid information. 28 years eating legumes very regularly make it hard to believe that your digerstive tract gets used to it. Mine hasn't, you just live with it.